# How can I put href into my code in dropdown

Tags: html, css

So, I got my Dopdown for Languages, I want to make a href if I press on "English", how can I do that?

```
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <div class="sl-nav">
                      Sprache:
                      <ul>
                        <li><b>Deutsch</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          <div class="triangle"></div>
                          <ul>
                            <li><i class="sl-flag flag-de"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span  class="active">Deutsch</span></li>
                            <li><i class="sl-flag flag-usa"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span>English</span></li> 
                            <li><i class="sl-flag flag-cz"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span>Česky</span></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Im pretty new, to HTML and don't know where to put my href

Comment: Wrap the content of each `li` in an anchor? (`<a>`)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the **a** anchor in the whole **li** element, so it works by clicking on the text and also the flag:

```
<li><a href="your_link"><i class="sl-flag flag-usa"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span>English</span></a></li>
```

also, remember to change your ids, they're all germany now

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anchor tag `<a>` on the elements:

```
<li><i class="sl-flag flag-usa"><div id="germany"></div></i><a href="the link u want to put">English</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but now the css of it changed. Can I add <a> to my css?

Comment: you should wrap the entire content not just the text

Comment: @Jerge, What do you mean by "the css of it changed"?

Comment: Never mind I used the other code of Javier, that works better with my current code. 
Thank you very much for helping!